# How to view the single service status via Ansible with modules rather than shell?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Need to check the Single service status on multiple system using Ansible playbook , is there a way to do using service modules rather than shell module ?

Answer (score 0):

With the `service` module (and the related more specific modules like `systemd`) you can make sure that a service is in a desired state.

For example, the following task will enable apache start at boot if not already configured, start apache if it is stopped, and report change if any change was made or ok if no change was needed.

```
- name: Enable and start apache
  service:
    name: apache
    enabled: yes
    state: started
```

Simply checking the service status without any change is not supported by those modules. You will have to use the command line and analyse the output / return status.

example with systemd

```
- name: Check status of my service
  command: systemctl -q is-active my_service
  check_mode: no
  failed_when: false
  changed_when: false
  register: my_service_status

- name: Report status of my service
  debug:
    msg: "my_service is {{ (my_service_status.rc == 0) | ternary('Up', 'Down') }}"
```

To be noted:

- `check_mode: no` make the task run wether or not you use '--check' on ansible_playbook command line. Without this, in check mode, the next task will fail with an undefined variable.
- `failed_when: false` refrains the task to fail when the return code is different from 0 (when the service is not started). You can be more specific by listing all the possible return code in normal conditions and failing when you get an other (e.g. `failed_when: not (my_service_status in [0, 3, X])`)
- `changed_when: false` makes the task always report ok except of `changed` by default for command and shell module.